# Using MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway with dynamic URI based on message header

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have the following configuration for sending SOAP requests as part of a integration flow, where `uriDefinedInApplicationProperties` is a fixed uri, defined in 'application.properties' file :

```
@Bean
public MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway outboundSOAPGateway()
{
    final MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway outboundGateway = new MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway(
            uriDefinedInApplicationProperties,
            requestMarshaller,
            responseMarshaller);
    outboundGateway.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList(retryOutboundGatewayAdvice));
    if (soapActionCallback!= null) {
        outboundGateway.setRequestCallback(soapActionCallback);
    }
    return outboundGateway;
}
```

Now i have the requirement that the URI of the remote SOAP server should be dynamically generated ( i'm planning on using message headers to store the URI).

I wanted to do something like the following, but MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway does not seem to support it, and i haven't been able to find how to do something similar using spring integration dsl:

```
@Bean
public MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway outboundSOAPGateway()
{
    final MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway outboundGateway = new MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway(
            message -> (message -> message.getHeaders().get("remote.uri.header"),
            requestMarshaller,
            responseMarshaller);
    outboundGateway.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList(retryOutboundGatewayAdvice));
    if (soapActionCallback!= null) {
        outboundGateway.setRequestCallback(soapActionCallback);
    }
    return outboundGateway;
}
```

I have noted that `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway` has a `setUriVariableExpressions(Map<String, Expression> uriVariableExpressions)` method, but i didn't find any clear documentation on what it is supposed to do and how it works.

Also i tried to do something like the following to create the outbound gateway, but it does not seem to support requestCallbacks nor advice chain.

```
Http.outboundGateway(message -> message.getHeaders().get("remote.uri.header"))
            .messageConverters(new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(
                    remoteRequestMarshaller,
                    remoteResponseMarshaller));
```

What is the best way to create a SOAP outbound gateway with retry advice and dynamically generated uri?

Answer (score 2):

The `advice` config is not a `MessageHandler` responsibility. If you use Java DSL, see a second argument (a `GenericEndpointSpec` lambda) of the `handle()` you use for that `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway`:

```
/**
 * Configure a list of {@link Advice} objects to be applied, in nested order, to the
 * endpoint's handler. The advice objects are applied only to the handler.
 * @param advice the advice chain.
 * @return the endpoint spec.
 */
public S advice(Advice... advice) {
```

Yes, I agree that `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway` (and its super class) doesn't support URI resolution against message at the moment. Feel free to raise a GH issue to fix a gap with a SpEL  configuration like we have it for the mentioned `Http.outboundGateway`.

Meanwhile as a workaround you can consider to implement a `DestinationProvider` which reads an URI from a `TheadLocal` store. Before calling this gateway you should consult your message and store built URI into that `ThreadLocal` variable.